# Which Collection<String> to use to search data with the character by character input

Tags: java, collections

Not sure if the question is self explanatory or not but I was asked this question in one interview.

Lets say, we have one Input box in our UI(Say First Name) and we have one table in DB(Say Users). Someone comes and write "S" there and he is given one list of all people's name starting with "S", as a hint. Then he adds "A" in it and then he is given a list of people's name starting with "SA" and so on. To achieve this, we have our JSP->Controller->Service->DAO->DB.

So instead of hitting DB again and again, we keep the whole data in server's cache or in session in one Collection.

Then which collection we should use for this scenario where after every onChange() of input box we fetch the proper data from Collection and show it to the user? Assuming, we have millions of data per character.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer that the interviewer was probably angling for was `ConcurrentSkipListSet`.  You can read the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) here, review the methods, and figure out if it meets the requirements.

Comment: It looks like they are more useful in multi threading environment for con- currency. Our goal is to reduce the iteration here. How will I jump or reach to the Names that is starting with "S" and then 'SA" and so on and then fetch them.

Comment: @Jaikrat - Look again.  Hint: tailSet.  But if the collection doesn't need to be concurrent then TreeSet can be used in the same way.

Comment: Yup, somewhat true. I have created one program and tested. Actually, the req is when someone enters "S" the collection should give us name starting with "S" only. But tailSet() is giving us all the names starting with "S", "T", "U" ..."Z". But yes, it did skip the name starting with A,B...R. Thanks for that.